# IntelliJ JavaFX generate onAction does not get recognized

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I generated my GUI in scenebuilder and it looks fine. Now i want my button to do something so i write in the scenebuilder in the "On Action" section what my method should be called. Afterwards i go into my sample.fxml and then i want this onAddButtonClick method created. The basic procedure would be to press ALT + Enter and then there would be the suggestion to create this method in the controller. But it just does not work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="46.0" layoutY="11.0" text="Customer Manager">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="340.0" layoutY="10.0" text="Cargo Manager">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="710.0" layoutY="12.0" text="Options">
         <font>
            <Font size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ListView layoutX="16.0" layoutY="49.0" prefHeight="285.0" prefWidth="211.0" />
      <Label layoutX="21.0" layoutY="350.0" text="Name:" />
      <TextField layoutX="60.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="170.0" />
      <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAddButtonClick" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="178.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

this confused me

```
  <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="395.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAddButtonClick" text="Button" />
```

EDIT: found the solution i just added fx:controller="sample.Controller" at the end of the first line

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Intellij onAction looks like its not covered in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186854/javafx-intellij-onaction-looks-like-its-not-covered-in-controller)

Comment: I'm not sure if IntelIJ does this automatically or not, but the missing `fx:controller` attribute could be an issue (but maybe IntelIJ is supposed to do the controller creation with this tool???).

Comment: where to i put the fx:controller attribute? @fabian

Comment: ok nvm i figured it out will edit the post! thanks